# Calculate relative risk / riskratio with confindence interval for multiple outcome variables (logical) per group - using dplyr and gtsummary

Tags: r, tidyverse, gtsummary

I am trying to figure out a way to calculate relative risks / risk ratios with confidence intervals (and p-values) for **multiple** outcome variables (logical type) per group (factor type with a varying number of levels).

I want the first level of the grouping variable to be the reference (risk ratio = 1.0).

I am able to do this for **one** outcome variable at a time, but I can't figure out how to create a function to do this for multiple outcome variables.

Here is my example:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.3.2 ──
#> ✔ ggplot2 3.4.0      ✔ purrr   0.3.5 
#> ✔ tibble  3.1.8      ✔ dplyr   1.0.10
#> ✔ tidyr   1.2.1      ✔ stringr 1.4.1 
#> ✔ readr   2.1.3      ✔ forcats 0.5.2 
#> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
#> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

library(epitools)

# Use 'iris' dataset to create example
reprex.1 <-
  iris %>% 
  mutate(
    sepal.length.group = case_when(
      Sepal.Length < 5 ~ "< 5",
      between(Sepal.Length, 5, 6) ~ "5 - 6",
      between(Sepal.Length, 6, 7) ~ "6 - 7",
      Sepal.Length >= 7 ~ "≥ 7"
    ),
    
    sepal.length.group = factor(sepal.length.group, levels = c("< 5", "5 - 6", "6 - 7", "≥ 7")),
    
    outcome.var.1 = if_else(Sepal.Width < 3, TRUE, FALSE, NA),
    outcome.var.2 = if_else(Petal.Length < 3, TRUE, FALSE, NA),
    outcome.var.3 = if_else(Petal.Length < 1, TRUE, FALSE, NA),
  )

glimpse(reprex.1)
#> Rows: 150
#> Columns: 9
#> $ Sepal.Length       <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5…
#> $ Sepal.Width        <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3…
#> $ Petal.Length       <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1…
#> $ Petal.Width        <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0…
#> $ Species            <fct> setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, setosa, set…
#> $ sepal.length.group <fct> 5 - 6, < 5, < 5, < 5, 5 - 6, 5 - 6, < 5, 5 - 6, < 5…
#> $ outcome.var.1      <lgl> FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FA…
#> $ outcome.var.2      <lgl> TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRU…
#> $ outcome.var.3      <lgl> FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FA…

# Use 'summarise' to calculate number of TRUE and FALSE per outcome variable per level in grouping variable.
reprex.2 <-
  reprex.1 %>% 
  group_by(sepal.length.group) %>% 
  summarise(
    # use across() to calculate for multiple variables
    across(
      c(
        outcome.var.1, outcome.var.2, outcome.var.3
      ),
      list(
        n.true = ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE),
        n.false = ~ sum(!.x, na.rm = TRUE)
      )
    )) %>% 
  # Convert wide format into long format
  pivot_longer(
    !sepal.length.group, 
    names_to = c("outcome.variable", ".value"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)"
  ) %>% 
  arrange(outcome.variable, sepal.length.group)

reprex.2
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    sepal.length.group outcome.variable n.true n.false
#>    <fct>              <chr>             <int>   <int>
#>  1 < 5                outcome.var.1         4      18
#>  2 5 - 6              outcome.var.1        28      39
#>  3 6 - 7              outcome.var.1        21      28
#>  4 ≥ 7                outcome.var.1         4       8
#>  5 < 5                outcome.var.2        20       2
#>  6 5 - 6              outcome.var.2        30      37
#>  7 6 - 7              outcome.var.2         0      49
#>  8 ≥ 7                outcome.var.2         0      12
#>  9 < 5                outcome.var.3         0      22
#> 10 5 - 6              outcome.var.3         0      67
#> 11 6 - 7              outcome.var.3         0      49
#> 12 ≥ 7                outcome.var.3         0      12

# Make subset for one outcome variable
rr.selected <-
  reprex.2 %>% 
  filter(outcome.variable == "outcome.var.1") %>% 
  select(outcome.variable, sepal.length.group, n.true, n.false) 


# Calculate riskratio and CI using epitools::epitab
rr.calculated <-
  epitab(
    data.matrix(
      rr.selected %>% 
        select(n.false, n.true)
      ),
    method = "riskratio"
  )$tab %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  select(riskratio, rr.lower = lower, rr.upper = upper, p.value)
#> Warning in chisq.test(xx, correct = correction): Chi-squared approximation may
#> be incorrect

rr.calculated
#>   riskratio  rr.lower rr.upper    p.value
#> 1  1.000000        NA       NA         NA
#> 2  2.298507 0.9065373 5.827820 0.07156575
#> 3  2.357143 0.9175047 6.055688 0.06058654
#> 4  1.833333 0.5554287 6.051381 0.40968178

# Combine the calculated riskratios with the the other variables
rr.final <- 
  rr.selected %>% 
  bind_cols(as.data.frame(rr.calculated))

rr.final
#> # A tibble: 4 × 8
#>   outcome.variable sepal.length…¹ n.true n.false riskr…² rr.lo…³ rr.up…⁴ p.value
#>   <chr>            <fct>           <int>   <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 outcome.var.1    < 5                 4      18    1     NA       NA    NA     
#> 2 outcome.var.1    5 - 6              28      39    2.30   0.907    5.83  0.0716
#> 3 outcome.var.1    6 - 7              21      28    2.36   0.918    6.06  0.0606
#> 4 outcome.var.1    ≥ 7                 4       8    1.83   0.555    6.05  0.410 
#> # … with abbreviated variable names ¹​sepal.length.group, ²​riskratio, ³​rr.lower,
#> #   ⁴​rr.upper
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

**Summary of problem:**
How can I calculate risk ratios with confidence intervals for multiple outcome variables per group, using the `dplyr` syntax?
How can I make this into a function to use with the `gtsummary` package, and most likely by the `add_stat()` function?

*Best regards

Steffen, Ph.D. fellow

Denmark*

Comment: Check out the `add_stat()` function to add custom statistics to gtsummary tables

Comment: Thank you,  @DanielD.Sjoberg. I have been looking through the reference of `add_stat()`, but since I am not even able to do the calculations for multiple outcome variables "automatically" via `tidyverse`, I can't figure out how to implement this to a custom function for `add_stat()`.